# How to create a string grammar from {(,)}* set?

Tags: formal-grammar

How to create a grammar that would imitate all the strings from the from the set {(,)}*, and in which (lines) all the parantheses would hava a correct place?

I just do not know how to start, I am a bit newbie in grammars :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like
$$\begin{align}S&\to \epsilon\mid\texttt{(}S\texttt{)}S\end{align} $$
perhaps?